# Rq: Insert Multiple rows

Tags: python, bigdata, rq

I have a 5gb file. I want to extract from each row some info to store into a db. I tried to iterate over all the file rows, and to insert one by one by it takes more than 2 days. I was thinking to use an "asynchronous approach" with rq ( I want to divide the rows in n queue of rows_num / n jobs). This is what I tried:

```
def do_work(file_name, queue_length,func,redis_connection): 
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f: 
        queue_num = 1
        q = Queue(str(1), connection=redis_connection)
        rows = []
        for i, line in enumerate(f): 
            if i // queue_length == queue_num:
                rows.append(Queue.prepare_data(func, (line,), job_id=str(i)))
            else:
                q.enqueue_many(rows)          
                q = Queue(str(queue_num), connection=redis_connection)
                rows = [Queue.prepare_data(func, (line,job_id=str(i)))]
        q.enqueue_many(rows)
```

If I am not mistaken, this will not work as I expect (not in an asynchronous way) as it will execute the first queue than when it finishes, it will execute the second one, then the third one and so on.

How can I reach what I am expecting?

Comment: Using `asyncio` is the typical way to achieve asynchronicity, you need to understand the concepts of awaitables and future tasks, but that doesn't seem to be what is the issue here. File system write is incredibly slow and will take milliseconds even with an SSD. I haven't used `rq` and don't know for sure, but it looks like you are using `enqueue_many` to write to the filesystem repeatedly. This is inefficient,  just try to collect everything in the `rows` `list` and do a single `q.enqueue_many(rows)` at the end.